# Build C++ dll to both platforms (x86+x64) on build server

Tags: c#, c++, msbuild, teamcity

Is there a way to build (msbuild) a C++ library for 32 and 64bit on build server (TeamCity)?

My Solution consists of some C# projects (all AnyCPU) and one C++:

- Win32 -> build to x86
- x64 -> build to x64

tried it with this target in msbuild script:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <MSBuild Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'Win32' " Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" 
             Properties="Platform=x64;PlatFormTarget=x64" RunEachTargetSeparately="true" />
</Target>
```

but without success! (the platform selected in the configuration window will be used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a new configuration in VisualStudio to only build the native
C++ library for 32bit.

1. create a new configuration e.g. `NativeLibs_x86`
2. check Build checkboxes only for C++ lib and Platform to `Win32`
3. add a new target to build `NativeLibs_x86` to your msbuild script

> <Target Name="BuildNativeLibs">
>           <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFile)"
>                  Targets="Rebuild"
>                  Properties="Configuration=NativeLibs_x86;
>                  Platform=AnyCPU;
>                  DeployOnBuild=false"
>                  BuildInParallel="false"/>
>       </Target>

4. Consider target `BuildNativeLibs` in e.g. `BuildRelease` target